# Каталог с музыкой при нажатии переходит на страницу альбома и выводит картинку, название, описание

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');
    $query = $conn -> query ("SELECT albums.id, albums.title, albums.raiting, albums.cover, artists.name 
        FROM albums JOIN artists ON albums.artist=artists.id");
    $ids = $_GET['artist.id'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Music</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="w90">
    <header></header>
    <h1>Музыка</h1>
    <div>
        <input id="find-field" type="text" placeholder="Поиск"></input>
    <div/>
    <div id="albums" class="albums">
        <?php while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
        { ?>
            <div class="album">
                <div class="album-image">
                    <a href="albom.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                        <img src="img/cover/<?php echo $row['cover'];?>"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="rating r-<?php echo $row['raiting'];?>">
                </div>
                <h3>
                    <a href="albom.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></a>
                </h3>
                <h4>
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $row['name'];?></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
Сам альбом
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');
    $query = $conn -> query ("SELECT albums.id, albums.title, albums.raiting, albums.cover, artists.name 
        FROM albums JOIN artists ON albums.artist=artists.id");
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM operacyi WHERE ids=' . $_GET['ids'];
    $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM operacyi WHERE id=' . $_GET['id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>album</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class=".wFull">
    <div id="cover-bg">
        <img src="img/cover/<?php $cover = sql_get_row("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id");?>"/>
        <h2 class="artist-name"><?php echo $row['name'];?></h2>
        <img class="arrow" src="img/angle-down-solid.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="w600">
    <h1><?php echo $row['title'];?></h1>
    <p>
        <?php echo $row['description'];?>
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы вопрос забыли написать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Надо чтобы нажимал на какой нибудь альбом и id, atrist передавался в следующий файл, пробовал это SELECT id FROM operacyi WHERE id= $_GET[$id] не хочет принимать. В общем чтбы айди и артист передавался для загрузки нужных картинок, названия и поисания